# Import Tensorflow without NVIDIA GPU (ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll')

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed the `tensorflow` package using Anaconda Navigator. When I try to run `import tensorflow` in a jupyter notebook I get the following error:

```
   OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py in preload_check()
     61         try:
---> 62           ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
     63         except OSError:

D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:

OSError: [WinError 126] Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     28 # Perform pre-load sanity checks in order to produce a more actionable error
     29 # than we get from an error during SWIG import.
---> 30 self_check.preload_check()
     31 
     32 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

D:\ProgrammFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py in preload_check()
     68               "'C:\\Windows\\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you "
     69               "have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed."
---> 70               % build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
     71 
     72       if hasattr(build_info, "cudart_dll_name") and hasattr(

ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.
```

I'm aware that I cant use `tensorflow-gpu` because I don't have an NVIDIA GPU. Therefore I don't even have installed the `tensorflow-gpu` package.

How am I supposed to import TensorFlow without having a CUDA installed?

Comment: What is the command that you used to install `tensorflow`?

Comment: I used Anaconda Navigator.The packages are called "tensorflow (2.1.0)","tensorflow-base", "tensorflow-estimate". They have been installed after installing "keras"

Comment: Could you uninstall it and run this command `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` in the terminal?

Comment: Great! Thank you, it works. Could you please write a short answer to this question and explain briefly why this solution works? That would be awesome.

Comment: Glad I could help, I've added the answer as requested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was only in your installation. Using anaconda-navigator isn't the best way to install `tensorflow`. My assumption is either `tensorflow-base` or `tensorflow-estimate` has a GPU dependency which is the reason why it kept showing the posted error message.

The best way to install `tensorflow` using `conda` is via `conda-forge` channel which is the official way. You can do that by running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```